# Is it possible to swap key switches in a mechanical keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

Some mechanical keyboards use Cherry MX keyswitches in varying colours, with varying differences to actuation force, tactile feedback and audible feedback.

Is it possible on these keyboards to change the keyswitches without damaging the keyboard or requiring any soldering on the internals?

I'm afraid to disassemble my keyboard to find out as doing so will void any warranty.

Is it a case where some keyboards will be able to do this and others won't?

Comment: It would be nice if the person who down-voted would be courteous enough to leave a comment saying why... Is this a bad question? Off topic? Duplicate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That may depend on the keyboard. Specifically, if the keys are plate mounted, you probably will not be able to swap without desoldering. If they are PCB mounted, then [this thread](https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=12790.0) includes a video demonstrating a solder-free swap. (Also [Internet Archive copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20140715214313/http://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=12790.0) and [direct link to YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GivKt63dLvA).)